Why is GCC generating so much code for this std::bit_cast?
I was looking at the code generated when I use std::bit_cast to convert from arrays of a user-defined strong type to the underlying type and noticed that GCC seems to emit some code even at high optimization levels. For
#include <array>
#include <bit>

struct StrongType {
    float value;
};

std::array<float, 2> bitCast(std::array<StrongType, 2> const a) {
    return std::bit_cast<std::array<float, 2>>(a);
}

std::array<float, 3> bitCast(std::array<StrongType, 3> const a) {
    return std::bit_cast<std::array<float, 3>>(a);
}

with -std=c++20 -O3 Clang 18.1.0 produces just ret in both cases, but GCC 14.1 produces
bitCast(std::array<StrongType, 3ul>):
        movd    DWORD PTR [rsp-16], xmm1
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp-32], xmm1
        movd    xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsp-32]
        ret

for the overload that casts an array of three elements.
Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/e4ePPzMhY.

Why is GCC generating this?
Is std::bit_cast the shortest way of performing this kind of conversion with no undefined behavior?
Is it reasonable to assume that std::bit_cast in cases like these will be zero-cost in the future?


Looks like the , 3 makes GCC (incorrectly) assume that the parameter might not be properly aligned.  The , 2 size optimizes nicely (as seen in the Godbolt link), as does , 4.

Why do you pass the arguments by const-value, not const-ref ?

This (possibly relevant) example is even weirder: https://godbolt.org/z/dWWKdh6Pe. I really don't get the point of the GCC-generated assembly in the 3-float case.
